# Editing .js with Jint

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I am trying to edit the below javascript with jint. I really only want to edit `var antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey = '';` and set the proxy settings in `defaultConfig` while at runtime. I have a winforms, I will be passing the two values into the method I call to edit it. Here is the js,

```js
// Public config

var antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey = '';

var defaultConfig = {
    // settings
    enable: true,
    account_key: antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey,
    auto_submit_form: true,
    play_sounds: false,
    delay_onready_callback: false,

    where_solve_list: [], // i.e. ['example.com', 'www.ladysproblems.com']
    where_solve_white_list_type: false, // true -- considered as white list, false -- black list

    solve_recaptcha2: true,
    solve_recaptcha3: true,
    recaptcha3_score: 0.3,
    solve_invisible_recaptcha: true,
    solve_funcaptcha: true,
    solve_geetest: true,
    solve_hcaptcha: true,
    use_predefined_image_captcha_marks: true,

    solve_proxy_on_tasks: false,
    user_proxy_protocol: 'HTTP',
    user_proxy_server: '',
    user_proxy_port: '',
    user_proxy_login: '',
    user_proxy_password: '',

    use_recaptcha_precaching: false,
    k_precached_solution_count_min: 2,
    k_precached_solution_count_max: 4,

    dont_reuse_recaptcha_solution: true,
    start_recaptcha2_solving_when_challenge_shown: false,
    solve_only_presented_recaptcha2: false,

    // use_recaptcha_accelerator: false,

    // status
    account_key_checked: antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey ? true : false, // set after account_key check
    free_attempts_left_count: 15 // move to config
};
```

Here is my current code which executes, but it doesn't change the variable from what I can tell. I also haven't added editing the proxy settings first as I want to try to see if I can even change the api key variable. Once done I want to just save the file. This is my first time using jint so I am pretty inexperienced with it.

```
        public static void ReadJsFile(string api, string proxy)
        {
            string workingDirectory1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string filePath = workingDirectory1 + "\\anticaptcha\\js\\config_ac_api_key.js";

            var engine = new Engine();

            var antiCap = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            engine.Execute(antiCap);

            engine.SetValue("antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey", api);      
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After executing the line `engine.Execute(antiCap)`, `defaultConfig` is already evaluated and filled with the value of `antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey` at the time of the evaluation, which is an empty string. Changing the value of `antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey` afterwards won't affect `defaultConfig`.

To get what you want, do not define `antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey` in the JS file, and set its value using Jint before executing the script:

```
public static void ReadJsFile(string api, string proxy)
{
    string workingDirectory1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string filePath = workingDirectory1 + "\\anticaptcha\\js\\config_ac_api_key.js";
    var engine = new Engine();
    var antiCap= File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    engine.SetValue("antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey", api);
    engine.Execute(antiCap);
}
```